# Calculating homemade yogurt's fat

Tags: fat, yogurt

I'm currently using a very "rich" whole milk with 3.8% fat. Out of one liter milk, I get 850cc yogurt (as some part of the water will evaporate throughout cooking. 
The question is: how much fat will contain the yogurt?
A stupid calculation would be

```
3,8% divided by 1000cc = 0,38
3,8% divided by  850cc = 0,44
```

Is the math correct? Is this yogurt extremely fat?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct calculation. There is nothing going on in the yogurt to change its fat content. (You can't use a similarly easy calculation for carbohydrates, as the culture consumes some of them).

Your math is correct. Is it "extremely fat"? In yogurt-terms, not at all. I have regularly seen 10% yogurt from cow's milk; yogurts from other species can easily be fatter. So, compared to general yogurt numbers, it's just a normal yogurt.

Comment: It might be easier to measure by weight. (I think this is accurate, though - the density of yogurt isn't that far off from water/milk.)

Comment: Glad to know! I ask because this yogurt simply rocks! Thick, fresh...lovely! Every day 150g!

Comment: I didn't even pay enough attention to notice these are milliliters. Jefromi is right, the calculation has to be done by weight and will be slightly imprecise when done by volume. The number on your milk carton is already by weight.

Comment: Ok, supposing 1kg of milk and 850g of yogurt the correct calculation should be: 3,8% = 3,8 / 100 = 0,038 (percentage) ----->
850g x 0,038 = 32,3g (fat per 850g) ----->
(100g x 32,3g) / 850g = 3,8g (fat per 100g)